# Adding form fields using javascript in a jsp program?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

Basically I have a javascript function that allows a user to add forms as he/she wishes. I have a couple of input fields and I have no problem adding them. Here is my code.

```
<script>

var counter = 1;

function addInput(divName){
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML =         
          "<center><br><hr width='300'>\n\
                   Control Number: <br><input type='text' name='control_number'>\n\
                   Date of Pull Out: <br><br><input type='date' name='pulloutdate'>\n\
                \n\Item Description: <br><br> <select name='des'>\n\
                \n\
                   <%  while(rSelectRecord.next()){ %>
         <option value="<%=rSelectRecord.getString("item_code")%>"><%=rSelectRecord.getString("item_code")%></option>
          <% } %>
</center>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
}

</script>
```

However in my innerHTML, the values in my item description should be taken from the database that I have created. I was thinking of doing it that way where I put a scriplet inside and get my values. It does not work.

Is there any way I could add forms with selections taken from a database and place it in a javascript function? Or is there a way I could create my form in a different page and just include it in my newdiv.innerHTML = "filenamehere"? Please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work. I think your scriptlets are just adding unescaped newlines to your javascript string, breaking it. So, try this:

```
            \n\
               <%  while(rSelectRecord.next()){ %>\
     <option value='<%=rSelectRecord.getString("item_code")%>'><%=rSelectRecord.getString("item_code")%></option>\
      <% } %>\
        \n</select>\n\
</center>";
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it doesn't work. It doesn't add any more forms when there is a scriplet.

Comment: If the scriptlet doesn't throw an error, it should work. I do it all the time. To debug it, try removing all the line breaks from your `newdiv.innerHTML =` statement. Having it all on one line and balancing the quotes should get it working. Make sure you alternate double and single quotes if you're trying to nest (see updated answer).